# Error when trying to use CanvasJS via RequireJS

Tags: requirejs, canvasjs

I'm trying to use **CanvasJS** inside my project. I'm using **RequireJS** to manage the modules, and have this in the main script:

```
define(['domReady',"canvasjs","common-functions"], function(domReady,CanvasJS) {
    domReady(function () {
        window.CanvasJS = CanvasJS;
        init_page_select();
    });
});
```

This is what I have in my requireJS config file for the path:

```
 "paths": {
      // other stuff here
      "canvasjs": "node_modules/canvasjs/dist/canvasjs.min"

    },
```

I can see the **canvasjs.min.js** file being grabbed fine - but then I get this weird error:

```
ReferenceError: intToHexColorString is not defined[Learn More] canvasjs.min.js:7:7042
    [33]</n.prototype.render https://www.test.org/2018/js/lib/node_modules/canvasjs/dist/canvasjs.min.js:7:7042
    [28]</n.prototype.render https://www.test.org/2018/js/lib/node_modules/canvasjs/dist/canvasjs.min.js:5:14150
    n/this.render https://www.test.org/2018/js/lib/node_modules/canvasjs/dist/canvasjs.min.js:8:17771
    init_page_select https://www.test.org/2018/js/lib/spot_view_stats.js:83:2
    <anonymous> https://www.test.org/2018/js/lib/spot_view_stats.js:4:3
    domReady https://www.test.org/2018/js/lib/domready.js:105:13
    <anonymous> https://www.test.org/2018/js/lib/spot_view_stats.js:2:2
    execCb https://www.test.org/2018/js/lib/require.js:5:12859
    check https://www.test.org/2018/js/lib/require.js:5:6575
    enable/</< https://www.test.org/2018/js/lib/require.js:5:9031
    bind/< https://www.test.org/2018/js/lib/require.js:5:812
    emit/< https://www.test.org/2018/js/lib/require.js:5:9497
    each https://www.test.org/2018/js/lib/require.js:5:289
    emit https://www.test.org/2018/js/lib/require.js:5:9465
    check https://www.test.org/2018/js/lib/require.js:5:7169
    enable/</< https://www.test.org/2018/js/lib/require.js:5:9031
    bind/< https://www.test.org/2018/js/lib/require.js:5:812
    emit/< https://www.test.org/2018/js/lib/require.js:5:9497
    each https://www.test.org/2018/js/lib/require.js:5:289
    emit https://www.test.org/2018/js/lib/require.js:5:9465
    check https://www.test.org/2018/js/lib/require.js:5:7169
    enable https://www.test.org/2018/js/lib/require.js:5:9358
    init https://www.test.org/2018/js/lib/require.js:5:5716
    h https://www.test.org/2018/js/lib/require.js:5:4287
    completeLoad https://www.test.org/2018/js/lib/require.js:5:12090
    onScriptLoad https://www.test.org/2018/js/lib/require.js:5:13014
```

I'm invoking it with:

```
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("thegraph",
{
  title:{
   text: impressionText
 },
  theme: "theme2",
 axisX: {
   valueFormatString: "MMM-DD-YYYY",
   labelAngle: -50
  },
  axisY:{
    valueFormatString: "#0",
    title:  impressionText
  },
 data: [
 {
  type: "line",
  showInLegend: true,
  legendText: legendText,
  dataPoints: dataPoints
}
]
});

chart.render();
```

Interestingly, if I tell it to load **canvasjs.js** instead of **canvasjs.min.js**, I get another error:

> ReferenceError: intToHexColorString is not defined[Learn More]

Answer (score 0):

OK so the problem seemed to be my version. For some reason "npm install canvasjs" was installing 1.8.1, but 2.2 was out. As per their request, I updated it to 2.2 and it sorted the problem. It seems weird npm is running such an outdated version though